# Running code with node.js gives an error, but without node it works perfectly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im using Visual Studio Code. When i run my code normally(CTRL+ALT+N), it works perfectly. However, when i run it in Windows Powershell with node.js, it gives me an error. 
This is my code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}role`)) {
        const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
        message.delete(1);
        message.reply("Choose title (message will expire after 10 seconds")
        .then((r) => {
            sleep(1)
            botlastMSG = message.channel.lastMessageID
            r.delete(10000)
        })
        message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 10000, errors: ['time']}).then(collected => {
            var response = collected.first().content
            var respMsG = message.channel.lastMessageID
          message.channel.fetchMessage(botlastMSG).then(msg => msg.delete(1));  


          if (response == "cancel") return message.channel.send("Cancelled!").then(r => r.delete(2000))
          newArr.push(response)
          show = 1  
          message.channel.fetchMessage(respMsG).then(msg => msg.delete(1))//deletes response          
        }).catch(err =>{message.reply("Time has expired!").then(r => r.delete(3000))})  

        while (show == 0) {
            await sleep(1)
        }
```

And this is the error i get when its run with node:

```
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
    at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\botd\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:85:15)
    at then (C:\Users\Adam\Desktop\botd\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:23652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:23652) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What command did you use to run it with node?

Comment: I used "node ."

Comment: Have you tried debugging via `console.log()` to further investigate what exactly is happening?